# combo box values not working for quote calculator

Tags: javascript

This is a piece of the code I'm working with and the only part giving me problems. I'm using the combo box to give me both the Line2_flag and the screencharge. Without this particular piece of code the form works fine so I know it's just this snippet. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
<select name="inkcolors" size="1" id="inkcolors" class="FormStyle" 
<option selected value="1">1&lt;/option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>


var = Line2_flag;
var = screencharge;

if(form.inkcolors[1].selected){
Line2_flag = 1.75;
screencharge = 1;
}

if(form.inkcolors[2].selected){
Line2_flag = 2.25;
screencharge = 2;
}

if(form.inkcolors[3].selected){
Line2_flag = 2.75;
screencharge = 3;
}
```

Comment: Please don't copy paste your code, first understand what logic you have written. Declare your variables properly.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this method:

```
 <html>
    <form>
        <select name="inkcolors" size="1" id="inkcolors" class="FormStyle" 
    <option selected value="1">1</option>
    <option  value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    </form>

    <script>
        var Line2_flag = null;
    var screencharge = null;
    var field = document.forms[0].elements['inkcolors'];
    var selected = field.options[field.selectedIndex].value;

    if (selected === "1") {
        Line2_flag = 1.75;
        screencharge = 1;
    } else if (selected === "2") {
        Line2_flag = 2.25;
        screencharge = 2;
    } else if (selected === "3") {
        Line2_flag = 2.75;
        screencharge = 3;
    }

    </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: YES!!! Thank you SO much!! That worked perfectly! I've been driving myself crazy over this. Much appreciated. Have a great weekend!